# Banco de Dados do SAT CFe Fiscal

Tags: php, mysql, aplicação-web, erp

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação WEB em PHP, alguém que já Fez um sistema que emite SAT pode me informar se é necessário que o usuário possua o banco de dados do SAT, ou uma copia dele, no computador local? ou posso manter um banco MySQL em um servidor sem problemas fiscais?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O **equipamento SAT** deve estar instalado e disponível (pronto para uso) no estabelecimento. Se você se refere ao banco de dados da Aplicação Comercial usada no estabelecimento, a legislação tributária brasileira exige que os dados estejam disponíveis em servidores **dentro do território nacional**, mas isso varia de Estado para Estado.

Apenas para exemplificar, em Estados que aderiram ao **PAF-ECF** (*que não tem nada a ver com o SAT*) é exigido que o banco de dados esteja disponível no estabelecimento (a menos que isso tenha mudado desde 2014).

No Estado de São Paulo o contribuinte que emite documentos fiscais SAT-CF-e deve preocupar-se em arquivar de forma segura os arquivos XML assinados, que tem validade jurídica e são o documento fiscal em si (existem apenas na forma eletrônica).

Os detalhes estão na legislação da CAT-147/2012 disponível no site [Secretaria Fazenda do Estado de São Paulo](http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat/).

Comment: Muito obrigado por esclarecer minha duvida.